# Exiting a node script after sending Push Notifications

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, web-push

The code is long but the question is probably elementary.

```
const webpush = require('web-push');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = require('./../config.json');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.pushNotifications.host,
  user: config.pushNotifications.user,
  password: config.pushNotifications.password,
  database: config.pushNotifications.database
});

con.connect(function(err) {});

return sendNotif();

function sendNotif() {
  const type = argv.type;
  const dataToSend = {
    "title": argv.title,
    "message": argv.message
  };

  return getSubscriptions()
    .then(function(subscriptions) {
      let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();

      for (let i = 0; i < subscriptions.length; i++) {
        let subscription = subscriptions[i];

        let pref = subscription.preferences.split('');

        if (pref[type - 1] == 1) {
          promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => {
            return triggerPushMsg(subscription, JSON.stringify(dataToSend));
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
}


function triggerPushMsg(subscription, dataToSend) {
  return webpush.sendNotification(subscription, dataToSend)
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.statusCode === 410) {
        return deleteSubscriptionFromDatabase(subscription.endpoint);
      } else {
        log.warn('Subscription is no longer valid: ', err);
      }
    });
}

function deleteSubscriptionFromDatabase(endpoint) {
  let sql = 'DELETE FROM subscriptions WHERE endpoint = ?';

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    con.query(sql, [endpoint], function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw reject(err);
      }
      log.debug('Deleted successfully from database. endpoint: ', endpoint);
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
}

function getSubscriptions() {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM subscriptions';

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw reject(err);
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

This code fetches some subscriptions from a MySQL database and sends notifications to it.
I have skipped the VAPID keys initialisation part but I have done it correctly in my program as it runs fine and the notifications get delivered. But the problem is, once I run it using the command-

```
node test/notification-trigger.js --type <type> --title "<title>" --message "<message>"
```

the program does not terminate automatically.

What needs to be changed here?
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: just use `process.exit(0)`

Comment: But that's probably just a hack. I want it to end the proper way after all notifications have been sent.

Comment: Also, if I use `exit`, it ends before sending the notifications

Comment: Why should it be a hack? It's the proper way to end an app. Just chain a then after the sending function

Comment: @baao I'm gonna try your code but I think that would make it exit after sending notification just to the first subscribed user.

Comment: Yeah, you need to chain it after the looping function

Comment: @baao if we run a simple node script with a single function, it exits automatically, but it doesn't occur here. Could you provide some explanation?

Comment: Found the solution! Just needed to add `con.end();`
It wasn't exiting because the sql connection still existed.